# Getting corrupted localized strings in json using javasacript

Tags: javascript, bash, automation, scripting, localization

I have below two objects. One is containing value of English string and another containing the localized value of each available English string.

In **localeGenerator.js** is the file having below code.

```
/*English Strings/*
const filteredKeys = {
        "Select a connection" : "Select a connection",
        "Script Viewer" : "Script Viewer",
        "Execution Script" : "Execution Script",
        "Workflows" : "Workflows",
        "Select Workflow" : "Select Workflow",
};

/*localized value with respect to English string*/
const translations = {
  "Saved Actions": "Actions enregistrées",
  "Select a connection": "Sélectionner une connexion",
  "Execution Script": "Exécution Script",
  "Close": "Fermer",
  "Workflows": "Workflows",
  "Select Workflow": "Sélectionner un workflow",
  "Clone": "Cloner"
 };

let outputFileJson = {};
let notFoundTranslatedValues = [];

for (element in filteredKeys) {
  if (element in filteredKeys) {
    if (translations[element] === undefined) notFoundTranslatedValues.push(element);
    outputFileJson[element] = translations[element];
  } else {
    notFoundTranslatedValues.push(element);
  }
}
```

Now When I'm trying to execute below command in vscode terminal, A json named **outputResult** is getting generated but with **corrupted** localized value.

```
node .\localeGenerator.js > outputResult
```

Not sure what I'm missing here. Could someone help me out here.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure of the code you wrote as example? I think it's not what you really have...

Comment: I would console.log outputFileJson somewhere and verify that part works.  If so then I would guess that the bash `>` operator is not writing out the file with the correct encoding.

Comment: correct, in console everything looks ok. @James